# How to load ActiveForm Page Faster in Yii2 Framework

Tags: yii2

Here i like to explain my problem clearly,

i had a `ActiveForm` page For `Claim Table`, it has fields `company_name`, `employee_code`, `employee_name`, `email`.

This page has several dependent dropDown, that means if i select `company_name`, it automatically populate to dependent `employee_code` to belongs to that company_name, then if i select `employee_code` it will automatically populate the dependent `employee_name`, `email`, `phone_no.`

Now the problem employee_table contains more than `35000` record, so while hitting `create` button, it taking `5 mins` to load the `ActiveForm page`.

Help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need load all records in dropdown list. Use ajax to get required `employee_code`.

This is example from [creating a dependent dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2/) tutorial.

```
echo $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList($dataCategory, 
         ['prompt'=>'-Choose a Category-',
          'onchange'=>'
            $.post( "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('post/lists?id=').'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
              $( "select#title" ).html( data );
            });
        ']);
```

Also you can use [depdrop plugin](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) and see how works [select2 plugin](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) for yii2.

Comment: Am already using this code only, but i dont know why this taking time load page

Comment: Html contain that many records? If yes it's required lot of time to render. If not, please, update posts include your controller code.

Comment: yes, html dropdown contains all the record, what i need to do now

Comment: Anyway you should not load that big amount data in html. See how works [that depdrop plugin](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop) and [select2 widget](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2). You need load data as it needed.

Comment: i have multiple action class in my controller. but it has only one url, in one dependent dropdown i will retrieve data from three tables and show it in three dropdown fields , how can i perform this using karthik dependent dropdown bcoz its looking for only one ur1

Comment: Try write one callback method on three dropdown fields that will update at once all three dropdowns, or decouple urls.